# coffeescript $.post get string from return object

Tags: javascript, json, post, coffeescript

I have a little problem. When I call

```
myVar = $.post('/check_2/', JSON.stringify({"newname": window.NEWNAME,}), callback, 'json')
```

in 'myVar' I have an object, so, when I do `console.log myVar`, I get something like:

```
Object {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function,getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function (a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}
always: function (){i.done.apply(i,arguments).fail.apply(i,arguments);return this}
complete: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
[...]
```

If I make `console.log myVar.success` (for example), It prints what it's shown in success, but, if I make `console.log myVar.responseText` (where the result of the call is), I keep getting `undefined`, so I can never really access the data I'm interested in.

Any ideas how can I access that data??

I know that I'm misunderstanding something about post calls, but as I have the misunderstanding, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I used post instead of get because I really need to send data to the backend, so I can make some checks in DB

**EDIT:**
Where I make console.log:

```
check2: (callback) ->
  console.log "Starting..."
  myVar = $.post('/check_2/', JSON.stringify({"newname": window.NEWNAME,}), callback, 'json')
  console.log myVar
  console.log "success example"
  console.log myVar.success
  console.log "responseText"
  console.log myVar.responseText
```

**EDIT 2**
Here's a photo of the object being showed by `console.log myVar`
[image: Image explaining returned object]

Comment: Where are you calling `console.log` (inside or outside the callback)?

Comment: You access the data inside the `callback`. As it stands you are simply setting `myVar` to the promise returned by the `$.post`. If you show us what you want to do with the data, we can probably provide better help.

Comment: ´check2: (callback) ->
      console.log "starting..."
      myVar = $.post('/check_2/', JSON.stringify({"newname": window.NEWNAME,}), callback, 'json')
      console.log myVar´

Comment: The data I want to get is a dictionary where I have what I need to load user's profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is an AJAX call, it doesn't return the server's response, it returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) promise:

> **jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )**
>   Returns: **jqXHR**
>
> **Description:** Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.

If you want the data from an AJAX call, then you have to get it from the callback:

```
fn = (data, status, jqxhr) ->
    # Your data is in `data` so do what you
    # need to do with `data` around here
    ...
    # And then call the other `callback` function
    # by hand.
    callback(data, status, jqxhr)

$.post('/check_2/', JSON.stringify({"newname": window.NEWNAME,}), fn, 'json')
```